# Como identificar semanalmente clientes que aparecem em uma tabela e não em outra em sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá, tudo bem galera?

Bom, preciso identificar semanalmente clientes que tem um plano ativo porém não utilizaram o plano naquela semana.

Tenho duas tabelas, uma que consta o tipo de plano do cliente e outra que consta os clientes que usaram o serviço.

Como faço para dar um Join entre essas duas tabelas de forma que ele me traga por semana os clientes que tinham um plano ativo, porém não usaram o serviço em determinada semana?

PS: Os clientes tem Id único e ambas tabelas possuem esse id.

Na tabela de clientes que utilizaram serviço, a data já está em date_trunc week.

Na tabela de planos comprados , a data de compra e encerramento também já estão em date_trunc week.

E também já criei uma tabela auxiliar com todas as semanas de 2020 para agrupar essas duas tabelas.

Comment: Você avaliou a possibilidade de fazer uma junção entre a sua tabela auxiliar e a tabela de plano para as semanas em que o plano estivesse ativo e aí utilizar um `NOT EXISTS` para um subselect na tabela dos clientes que usaram o serviço correlacionando cliente e semana?

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Rogério! Não consegui entender muito bem o problema...

Verifique se é isso que vc precisa: O Mais simples seria criar uma job em seu banco que roda 1 vez por semana e nela colocar o retorno da query:

```
Select id, name from cli_plano where data_desativado > to_date('DD/MM/YYYY', '01/01/2020') and id not in (select id from cli_uso where data_uso between to_date('DD/MM/YYYY', '01/01/2020') - 7 and to_date('DD/MM/YYYY', '01/01/2020') )
```

Espero ter entendido corretamente o problema, Qualquer coisa me envie um exemplo de tabela com os mesmos campos.
Abraço.

Comment: Mysql tem funções que retornam a semana , veja se ajuda https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week